# Why is Code in Initializer of Singleton not executed on App Launch?

Tags: swift, singleton

**Context**

I have a `Singleton` which should perform some setup logic inside its private initializer. However, this code does not get executed on app launch.

---

**Code**

```swift
class SomeViewModel: ObservableObject {
    static let shared = SomeViewModel()

    private init() {
        fatalError() // Just to test whether the Code gets executed.
    }
}
```

---

**Question**

- The app does not crash with a `Fatal Error` even this should happen when the initializer gets executed. Why does this happen?

Comment: Do you ever call `SomeViewModel.shared`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `static let` is lazy. It won't be initialized until the first call to access the `shared` property. So your app won't crash until you do:

```
let x = SomeViewModel.shared
```